# Installilng GiNaC and CLN on windows

Tags: installation, git, cygwin, c++, libraries

I planned to move to Arch Linux but for the time being I'm unfortunately stuck with Windows.
I want to install GiNaC.
In its installation page it says to install CLN first so that is also something I need to tackle.
The problem is I have downloaded the said folders for both of these. They were in .tar.bz2 format. I right-clicked and it gave me an option to extract. So I extracted twice so they are both in normal folders.
I also installed cygwin at some point of searching for how to install. Even though I have it installed, I have no idea how to make use of it.

I am attaching images of what the downloaded folders look like after I had extracted them.
[The stuff in the cln folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9kxm.png),
[The stuff in the ginac folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdguj.png)

I also saw somewhere I was probably not supposed to extract the .tar.bz2 but I couldn't understand.
Also I don't know where to use `./config`. The page with instructions to install GiNaC asks me to do that. [This](https://www.ginac.de/tutorial/) is what I'm ``following" but it's all Chinese to me. I also have chocolatey installed. From what I know it helps in easy installations.

It's been a few days and it's gotten really frustrating searching for stuff and not understanding what to do. Detailed instructions would be extremely appreciated

Comment: One possibility for you (I do this) is to run your Linux system as a virtual machine. Then you can work in Linux and Windows at the same time. Something to consider.

Comment: CLN is already available as Cygwin package https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/cln-src.html. Install `libcln-devel` before building GiNac

Comment: Thanks that was an easy shortcut. I have done it. Do I need to change path variables or something or is it done automatically? Also what would be the next step.